# What is this "all"?

Tags: grammar

**I was connected to the all there is. BY GERRY WHITE**

Is "the" acceptable there?
There is no example like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's either an error or a poetic use of language.  If the latter, it is better conceived of as **I was connected to the All-There-Is.**  The expression **all there is** is being used as a synonym for **universe**, and **universe** definitely takes a definite article.

Answer (score 0):

> I was connected to the all there is. [INCORRECT]

It is incorrect to use ***the*** there. Generally a Pre-Determiner (here *all*) precedes the Central-Determiner (here *the*). Drop that *"the"* and the sentence would be correct.

---

There are situations where *the* can come before *all* as in the following sentence -

> Due to its bench seat, the all original Ford F100 has no center console or drink holders.

Here the determinative *all* is not part of Determinative Phrase (DP), rather it's part of the Adjective Phrase (AdjP) - *all original*. That's why the sentence is correct.

This is completely different to the one OP quoted, where *the* was part of the Fused Determinative Phrase.